# Match vocabulary words and phrases

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am writing an application/logic that has `vocabulary word`/`phrase` as an input parameter. **I am having troubles writing validation logic for this parameter's value**!

Following are the rules I've came up with:

- can be up to 4 words (with hyphens or not)
- one apostrophe is allowed
- only regular letters are allowed (no special characters like !@#$%^&*()={}[]"";|/>/? ¶ © etc)
- numbers are disallowed
- case insensitive
- multiple languages support (English, Russian, Norwegian, etc..) (so both Unicode and Cyrillic must be supported)
- either whole string matches or nothing

Few examples (in 3 languages):

```
// match:
one two three four
one-two-three-four
one-two-three four
vær så snill
тест регекс
re-read
under the hood
ONe
rabbit's lair

// not-match:
one two three four five
one two three four@
one-two-three-four five
rabbit"s lair
one' two's
one1
1900
```

Given the expected result provided above - could someone point me to right direction on how to create a validation rule like that? If that matters - I will be writing validation logic in `C#` so I have more tools than just `Regex` available at my disposal.

If that is going to be of any help - I have been testing several solutions, like these `^[\p{Ll}\p{Lt}]+$` and `(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)$`. The first regex seems to be doing a great job allowing just the letters I need (En, No and Rus), whereas the second rule set is doing great in using the `Lookahead` concept.

- `\p{Ll}` or `\p{Lowercase_Letter}`: a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant.
- `\p{Lu}` or `\p{Uppercase_Letter}`: an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.
- `\p{Lt}` or `\p{Titlecase_Letter}`: a letter that appears at the start of a word when only the first letter of the word is capitalized.
- `\p{L&}` or `\p{Letter&}`: a letter that exists in lowercase and uppercase variants (combination of Ll, Lu and Lt).
- `\p{Lm}` or `\p{Modifier_Letter}`: a special character that is used like a letter.
- `\p{Lo}` or `\p{Other_Letter}`: a letter or ideograph that does not have lowercase and uppercase variants.

Needless to say, neither of the solutions I have been testing take into account all the rules I defined above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
\A(?!(?:[^']*'){2})\p{L}+(?:[\s'-]\p{L}+){0,3}\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CGocLH/3/). *Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[^']*'){2})` - the string cannot contain two apostrophes
- `\p{L}+` - one or more Unicode letters
- `(?:[\s'-]\p{L}+){0,3}` - zero to three occurrences of

  - `[\s'-]` - a whitespace, `'` or `-` char
  - `\p{L}+` - one or more Unicode letters
- `\z` - the very end of string.

In C#, you can use it as

```cs
var IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\A(?!(?:[^']*'){2})\p{L}+(?:[\s'-]\p{L}+");{0,3}\z")
```

Comment: very nice! it works! Could you please elaborate - why is this important to use `\n` in negative lookahead when testing in web UI? Shouldn't negative lookahead exclude the newlines, rendering ALL of the lines non matches? (except maybe the last line?) On a side note - I have done one small adjustment to the pattern you have provided: `\p{L}+[']?` to allow words to end with apostrophe. I am not sure if this is supposed to be the case in my application but at least for now this will suffice :)

Comment: @Alex You ma use `'?` to match an optional apostrophe. When testing in an online Web regex tester, we use a single multiline string, but in real life, we'll be using separate standalone strings without line breaks, Excluding `\n` is only needed for the demo purposes here. Same as using a regular space instead of `\s`. If you really need to make sure your pattern does not span multuple lines, you could keep using `\n` in the negated character class and a `[^\t\p{Zs}]` instead of `\s`. Unfortunately, .NET regex does not support `\h`.